# Preserve comments when Overriding

Tags: c#, .net, conventions, xml-comments

Is there a way (tool, or something) that permits do not duplicate the same XML comments when inheriting/Overriding methods from the base classes?

Eg.:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represent a brand new object in .NET
/// </summary>
public class MyObject : Object
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Copy-Paste the same Xml comment 
    /// like in the base class is boring!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">and params too!! ((</param>
    /// <returns>this one too!!! (((</returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks as if sandcastle would require you to have references to their libraries in order to get this functionality. I'm not sure if that's correct or not as I only skimmed over the documentation. If that's a deal breaker you might want to keep an eye on `https://github.com/pmacn/DocPlagiarizer` as it matures. It's a custom build task that will copy comments for you as part of your build process. It currently only does `interfaces -> implementations` rather than `base classes -> sub classes` but pull requests or issue reports are welcome.Disclaimer: I created this beast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for `inheritdoc`:

```
/// <inheritdoc />
public override bool Equals(object obj)
```

This is not a [standard tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx) (so Intellisense may not support it, for exampple), but it's pretty commonly used - in particular, [Sandcastle supports it](http://www.ewoodruff.us/xmlcommentsguide/html/86453FFB-B978-4A2A-9EB5-70E118CA8073.htm).

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a tool, you can try [GhostDoc](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/46A20578-F0D5-4B1E-B55D-F001A6345748) extension for visual studio.
It helps you pre-generating comments and can take comments from base class.

As the generated comment is a regular comment, IntelliSense supports it properly but it's not magically updated when the base comment is changed.